# How to repeat drop down list again and again in same JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

Suppose that selected the one value in drop down list, then after selection of value in drop down list same drop down list regenerated again in same JSP Page(as a previous drop down list).

How is to possible?  How to do it?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Did you try anything for this?

Comment: yes . i am trying javascript and jquery but i didn't fine any solution?how to possible?please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Hard way of doing it
http://jsfiddle.net/daWd9/

Comment: thanks a lot....but it is not working when i select any value?Please my question?

Comment: use onchange event in first list and call a script which populates the duplicate list!

Comment: var opts = document.getElementById('list1');
var str = "<select id=\"duplist\">";
for(var i=0;i<opts.length;i++){
  str+="<option>"+opts[i].text+"</option>";
}
str+="</select>";
var oldContent = '';
if(document.getElementById("container").innerHTML!=''){
oldContent = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
}
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = oldContent+str;

Comment: In updated code new generated drop down box related to main drop down list.suppose i chose(select) second drop down box option then third drop down list generate not to select one drop down list?

Comment: and depend upon only option .if option are three then whole program only three drop down list regenerate only?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose consider that your source dropdown list id is 'list1'. By using document.getElementById('list1') you'll get the details of that element. Then use document.createElement to create a new dropdown list and get the properties from the existing one document.getElementById('list1').

Comment: in javascript no opton are available of document.createTag?

Comment: I want regenerate existing drop down list again ?not new

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you have to select multiple values from same options. 
I would have done it using jQuery UI. Please follow the link for demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple .

1. Open the link.
2. Start typing in textbox, options will auto-populate.
3. You can select one and again start typing.

It will be a good user-friendly solution, in my opinion.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks saurabh but i don't want to this way??i want to as regenerate drop down list??can you provide this way link

Comment: @shubhanshu - it will be gr8 if u can post the code u tried, so that we can get your requirement properly and may be we can modify your code to better results.

Comment: <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Select your favorite browser:
<select name="myList" onchange="put()">
  <option>Internet Explorer</option>
  <option>Netscape</option>
  <option>Opera</option>
</select>
<br><br>

</form>
</body>

</html>

Comment: if i select the any value then dropdown list regenerate again?

Comment: Then @DineshDu's answer is best suited for what you care looking for. +1 DineshDu.

Comment: but dinesh answer in not depend upon onchange method?

Answer (score 0):

There two solutions documented in StackOverflow using AJAX technology

[How to call AJAX request on dropdown change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429176/how-to-call-ajax-request-on-dropdown-change-event)

[How to call AJAX request on dropdown change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429176/how-to-call-ajax-request-on-dropdown-change-event)

Please see the above will help you.

By the way I don't understand why you need to

> regenerate  again in same JSP Page(as a previous drop down list).